# Sorting a list of lists in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Say I have a list inside a list, that is contained inside a  list.  For example:

```
foo = [[[2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3]], [[2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3]]]
```

And I wanted to sort it in order:

```
foo = [[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]]
```

I could use `[sorted(i) for i in foo]` to achieve this.  However is there some way to sort this list without list comprehension (or creating a new list)?

The values inside the lists themselves will change but do not need to be sorted.

Everything I have tried just boils down to the same method as above.

Comment: If you really need to do this, you should probably be using multi indexed pandas dataframes

Comment: Pandas seems like a complete overkill for this, so it's probably better using list comprehension, if that method is the best alternative @Nickpick

Comment: Whatever happened to `for i in range(len(foo)): foo[i].sort()`?

Comment: What in the world is wrong with a list comprehension? You could also just sort each list in the outer list using the `sort` method.

Comment: @RoryDaulton  Indeed,  nothing,  however I am interested in an alternative that does not create an entirely new list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to avoid creating a new list, then just iterate over the lists and call `.sort()`

```
>>> foo = [[[2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3]], [[2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3]]]

for i in foo:
    i.sort()

>>> foo                                                                         
[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind creating a new list, how about using `map` function:

```
In [1]: foo = [[[2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3]], [[2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3]]]

In [2]: list(map(sorted, foo))
Out[2]: [[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]]
```

Comment: your answer does not address _However is there some way to sort this list without list comprehension (or creating a new list)?_

Comment: What are you talking about? Where do you see _list comprehension_ in my answer? As about _creating a new list_, I already mention that in the first line.

Comment: without list comprehension or **creating a new list**? You are basically creating a new list which is not addressing the question.

Comment: Ok, you come up with a better answer. I'm not chasing votes here. I just wanted to enrich the post by adding more options to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: if so it is fine. No need to get upset, I am just commenting about your answer. I also tried to come up with a better answer, but I think I cannot find something better than AK47 answer which deserves to be upvoted!

Comment: This is not exactly what I asked for however, it's an interesting method, different from what I have seen previously, which I think is certainly worth an up-vote.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm upvoting this purely because of the above conversation in the comments